# Change directory working directory for previous directory in Shell Script

Tags: find, cd-command, command-substitution

Is there any way to achieve below.. I am stuck to perform my task.

I have written shell script which gives me correct output only when the script is getting executed on same month

below is the command which i am using in script

```
cd $(find /home/application/Files/output/$(date +%Y)/$(date +%m) -type d|sort -r |head -1)
```

Below is the directory format which is actually present in system

```
 /home/application/Files/output/2018/01/30
```

Now the issue is : when i execute my script it gives me below error

```
 find: `/home/application/Files/output/2018/02': No such file or directory
```

It's looking for `../2018/02` directory which is not yet created, so i need to perform my task on `/home/application/Files/output/2018/01/30`.

Comment: If date(1) is from GNU, look at: man date | m +/--date=STRING

Comment: am not sure how should i use your recommendation in below command 
`cd $(find /home/application/Files/output/$(date +%Y)/$(date +%m) -type d|sort -r |head -1)`

Comment: I want to move in the latest modified directory which is available under this path using below command
`cd $(find /home/application/Files/output/$(date +%Y)/` latest folder under this path ..!!

Comment: date +%Y/%m ; date --date="next month" +%Y/%m

Comment: Thanks for quick response however I want to perform some task under the directory.. 
My file is present under below directory
`/home/application/Files/output/2018/01/30`

Comment: if you want to `cd` into the most recent directory that actually exists, then why search for a YYYY/MM/DD directory that might not exist yet?   why not just search for the most recent YYYY/MM/DD directory: `cd $(find /home/application/Files/output/ -type d-regextype egrep -regex '.*/[0-9]{4}/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]$'  | sort -rV | head -1)`?  (note: requires GNU `find`)

Answer (score 1):

Why search for a YYYY/MM/DD/ directory that might not exist yet?

Just search for and `cd` to the most recent YYYY/MM/DD/ directory:

```
cd "$(find /home/application/Files/output/ -type d \
       -regex '.*/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]$' -print0 | 
     sort -rVz | head -z -n 1)"
```

Note: requires GNU `find`, `sort`, and `head` for the `-print0`, and `-z` NUL-delimiter options.

If you prefer PCRE style regular expressions, you could do this instead:

```
cd "$(find /home/application/Files/output/ -type d -print0 | 
        grep -z -P '/\d{4}/\d\d/\d\d$' | sort -rVz | head -z -n 1)"
```

---

Alternatively, if you have to use the current day's directory whether it is empty or not, make the directory first and then `cd` into it:

```
dir="/home/application/Files/output/$(date +%Y/%M/%d)"
mkdir -p "$dir"
cd "$dir"
```

`mkdir`'s `-p` option creates the directory if it doesn't already exist.  It also creates any required parent directories.  It does not cause an error or complain if the directory already exists.

Answer (score 0):

If the directories are always created the same day, or very close to the same date, they were named after:

```
cd $(find /home/application/Files/output/$(date +%Y)/ -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 \
  -mtime -2 -type d |sort -r |head -1)
```

I didn't test it. Maybe min/maxdepth needs to be 2. :)

This solutions requires the date of creation to be maximum 2 days old. Maybe you need to adjust that too.

Without newline:

```
 cd $(find somepath/$(date +%Y)/ -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -mtime -2 -type d |sort -r |head -1)
```

Comment: I used below command but gave this error..

`cd $(find /home/application/Files/output/$(date +%Y)/ -mtime -2 \ -type d -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 |sort -r |head -1) 

find: paths must precede expression:  -type`

Comment: Sorry, my fault, wrong parameter order. Corrected.

Comment: Used your corrected command, however again got below error

`find: Expected a positive decimal integer argument to -maxdepth, but got `1 -mtime'`

Comment: You need at least one blank between newline and -mtime, else `1-mtime` will be read. Of course, a blank before the linebreak can't be wrong. :)

Comment: IMy question might be silly.. I am new to linux so asking my concern... I got below message

`find: Expected a positive decimal integer argument to -maxdepth, but got `1 ' `

Comment: This is the command

`cd $(find /home/application/Files/output/$(date +%Y)/ -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1\  -mtime -2 -type d |sort -r |head -1)`

Comment: Yes. Either you delete the newline and the backslash after '-maxdepth 1', or you put a blank before or behind the backslash. The comment section isn't suitable for bigger code junks, especially not when they contain line breaks. Note the blank I added above. I will add a line without break. Read about line breaks in the shell - it is not special for find.

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU `date` and `bash` (or `ksh93`), this picks out today's directory but backtracks one day at a time if that date's directory is not found, until it finds an existing directory (or max 30 days back in time):

```
for (( i = 0; i < 30; ++i )); do
    dir="/home/application/Files/output/$( date -d "now -$i days" +'%Y/%m/%d' )"
    [ -d "$dir" ] && break
done

if [ ! -d "$dir" ]; then
    echo 'Can not find recent output directory!' >&2
    exit 1
fi

printf 'Using output directory "%s"\n' "$dir"
cd "$dir"
```